# How to move image in header?

Tags: html, css

How to only move the image in the header?

Here is the HTML I am using.

```
  <header>
  <figure class="navbar">
    <a href="index.html">
    <img src="/images/logo.webp" alt="Minecrft Logo" title="Minecraft" height="50"></a>
  </figure>
  </header>
```

And here is the CSS I am using:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    background-image:url(../images/header_background.png);
}
```

And it shows me this funny thing...

[image]

The entire header is moving together with the image :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img class="logo" src="/images/logo.webp" alt="Minecrft Logo" title="Minecraft" height="50">

.logo {
      position: relative;
      left: 45%
    }
```